# Flag weight gold badge for 750?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New badges for the increased flag-weight.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82799/new-badges-for-the-increased-flag-weight)

Now that the flag weight has been adjusted so that it can go all the way up to 750, would it make sense to have a gold badge to encourage people to reach this level?

Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see someone get there first, then perhaps.

Warning: the flag weight scale beyond 500 is not, shall we say.. *linear?*

Comment: I see - is it ever possible to actually get there (i.e. does it tend towards 750) or is it just far harder?

Comment: And since you can't get there...

Comment: @berry: No, you can't get there. For a flag you always only get at most 1/20th of what is still missing till 750.

Comment: @Jeff - On Super User, atleast [one person is almost there](http://superuser.com/users/45662/yhw42)

Comment: @sathya that might have been due to a bug / exploit in the way the flag was calculated up until about 8 hours ago.

Comment: Challenge accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached

Comment: @Jeff So can we have the gold badge now? ;-)

Comment: @Jeff whats the problem in giving the gold badge ? when a similar effort in edits earns the gold copy editor badge.