# New badges for the increased flag-weight

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badge-request, flag-weight

Because the [flag-weight has increased to 750](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178), and (if I understood it right) you'll get less and less weight with every flag towards 750, I'd like to suggest two new Badges:

- **Sheriff** *(Silver)*: Achieved a flag weight of 700
- **Clint Eastwood** or **Marshal**<sup>1</sup> *(Gold)*: Achieved a flag weight of 749

<sup>1</sup>: As suggested by [martin clayton](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138400/martin-clayton).

Edit:
I've started this bounty, because now that there are people actually getting a flag weight of 750 in multiple sites, don't you think it would be a good idea to implement this brilliant idea which is so popular with many users? <sub>Jeff? please?</sub>

Comment: the 750 badge could have the subtitle "I shot the asymptote"

Comment: Did you realise `Deputy` is a *SILVER* badge? What would that make your 2 badges?

Comment: @Richard: True, good point...I'd say silver and gold. But then there would be two silver badges and one gold.

Comment: I thought Mark said you can't ever reach 750...

Comment: @John, clearly he meant "**Chuck Norris**: Achieved a flag weight of 750"

Comment: Hardly a challenge @Boddy ;-) You're already at 615.9192, so keep up the good work

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Why do you think I'm proposing new badges? ;P And thanks, I'll keep flagging of course. :)

Comment: Are there any stats on how many people are >=700 and >=749?

Comment: @marcog: On SO 75 people have the Deputy-Badge, on SU 9, SF 5. I'd guess it's well under 25 people on all three sites.

Comment: @marcog: @Bobby: Yesterday there were probably quite a few that were >749, but after Marc's flag weight calculation fix I wouldn't be surprised if there aren't anyone over 700 even. I deleted my answer since after that fix it wasn't relevant any longer.

Comment: @ho1 Oh, that would explain the big drop in my flag weight. I'm hovering around 660 and if I'm not mistaken 14 valid flags will push me over 700. But it's not easy keeping it above 700 as you an 83% success rate (I think).

Comment: @marcog: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83084/my-super-awesome-flag-weight-dropped-what-gives

Comment: And, implemented just a few hours before the bounty expired.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about

[image]

for the gold badge?

I'd suggest that the level for the gold badge be tuned to require a similar effort to the existing 'Copy Editor' badge.

Comment: Perhaps, with the current asyptotic growth after 500, a gold `Marshal` (perhaps has too many military connotations?) or `Sheriff` badge around 650 would make sense? I think this is comparable to the difficulty of getting "Copy Editor".

Comment: @agf: The growth isn't asymptotic. You need 536 valid flags to get from flag weight 500 to flag weight 750 ([formula being used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569)). Which is an effort worth a gold badge IMHO - getting to 650 is relatively simple on the other hand.

Comment: My mistake; I'd read differently.

Comment: @martin Unless I'm much mistaken, this has been implemented today.

Answer (score 10):

My suggestion for a gold badge based on flag weight is that it involves sustaining a very high flag weight for a span of time or span of flags. i.e.

```
flagged X posts while maintaining a flag weight of at least Y
```

I'd say "flagged 100 posts while staying above 725" would be good starting point.

Comment: I would include time in it as well, so flags at least 20 posts a month for 6 months while maintaining a flag weight of at least Y

Comment: @Ian if the number of flags per month is high enough, simply multiply it with 6 months, given the flaggers some room for going on a vacation for instance

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that any 10K+ can get as much flag weight as they want just by “reflagging” items in the flag queue.   (10K+ users can see the flag queue)

So any badge should only be rewarded based on being the first person to flag an item.

Comment: One still has to get it right, i.e. not reflag anything what a moderator decides otherwise.

Comment: @Paule, getting it right takes very look time, the effert is tracking down the problem to be flagged.   Just find 1 in 5 items in the flag queue you know are correcly flagged and watch your flag rating go up fast.

Comment: I did this as soon as I reached 10k. Which lead to the question [Which actions using the 10k-moderator-tools do really help the diamond moderators?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96473/which-actions-using-the-10k-moderator-tools-do-really-help-the-diamond-moderators). You are right, the time-consuming part is finding new items - this should get a larger influence on badges and/or flag-weight.

Answer (score 4):

I propose a variation on this:

- Make Deputy bronze

  - Solves the "Two badges higher than silver" problem

- Lower Deputy requirement to 250 FW

  - Fits better with bronze

- Make Sheriff requirement 500 FW

  - Makes the distance between the 3 rungs 250-250 instead of 200-50

- Rename "Clint Eastwood"

  - Not everyone is going to know who Clint Eastwood is.

Comment: 250 still sounds a little much for a bronze badge... you already get a bronze badge by raising just *one* flag.

Comment: who is this Clint Eastwood you speak of?

Comment: @Bolt: Yeah, I thought about that, but this was the only way I could think of to fit two more badges above Deputy.

Answer (score 2):

[client-eastwood](/questions/tagged/client-eastwood)? Pah. Give me [jeff-atwood](/questions/tagged/jeff-atwood). He seems to have a knack for flagging things. Tagging even.

Look at Jeff's comment against this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82538/156011

I think he is far more recognizable as an enforce (good or bad) on SE than Clint who?

---

For those who have an issue with using `[tag:]` for styling, please, take your comments and put in a request for `[badge:]`